# how display checked filter variable value in url codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am a basic user of code igniter and PHP.I have some products page with filters. How to created a URL link like this:

`http://somepage.pl/products?color=red`

I know I can do above url when I will change the config line:

`$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;` on TRUE.

But I want to use this option only one controller and one function.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to rely on codeigniter's native URI rewriting.

By default, (I'm not getting into custom routes here, but you might if you understand them) URLs served by Codeigniter will look like this:

```
BASE URL/Controller/method/params
```

Base url will be what you define in the config and more often than not, it'll be the base domain of your site, like `example.com`.

Since CI is built based on MVC architecture, all your functionality must "live" on different methods within one or many controllers. So, for example, you might have a controller named `products` and within that controller you may have a method (for simplicity's sake: function) called `lookupProductById` that will take one parameter (`$product_id`). It'll look like this:

```
class Products extends CI_Controller {
   public function lookupProductById($product_id = null)
   {
      // whatever you need to do (like querying the database to fetch info for the product with a certain product ID) goes here
     // for instance, start by checking that the product ID was passed in the URI
     if  ($product_id == null)
     {
        // handle exception
     }

     else
     {
        // query the database and fetch info for the product whose ID is $product_id
     }

   }

}
```

so, when accessing `example.com/products/lookupProductById/8` you'll be able to fetch the info related to product ID 8

You may want to read the [CI documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/welcome.html) (the introductory chapters and tutorials will guide you through a (very) basic understanding of how MVC frameworks operate, how controllers, models and views interact to produce a result, etc.) to better understand what you're getting into :)